# Skip converting ">" to "&gt;" for an attribute value in xml in java

Tags: java

I am trying to edit the value of few attributes inside a xml file using Java.

Below code is being tried:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory fact= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
fact.setNamespaceAware(true);
fact.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
fact.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
fact.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation" +
        "/schema-full-checking", true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder=fact.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(fileName));
doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
Element rootElm=doc.getDocumentElement();
Element settingElm=(Element) rootElm.getElementsByTagName("ABC").item(0);
NamedNodeMap settingAttr=settingElm.getAttributes();
Node nod=settingAttr.getNamedItem(attribute);
if(nod==null){

}
else{
    nod.setTextContent(value);
}
TransformerFactory transformerFactory=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer=transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
DOMSource source=new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result=new StreamResult(new File(fileName));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Expected result is:

```
<'ABC ab="123>34"\>
```

Actual result is:

```
<'ABC ab="123&gt;34"\>
```

Kindly ignore the single quote for for left angle bracket in above two lines.

Comment: I can see only difference i.e. double quote at the end.

Comment: I meant that how can we avoid ">" being replaced by "&gt;". The single quote before ABC is not present in the data. It's here only just to have the complete data otherwise complete data were not visible.

Comment: As you can see in the possible duplicated answer above, you cannot use a plain ">" in an attribute value, because it is a special character in XML. So in the serialized XML the ">" is escaped with "&gt;". It is not replaced but escaped. If you parse the XML your parser will still get you ">" in the attribute value.

Comment: yeah, when i tried to fetch that value, it's in proper way. Thanks a lot.